# About derivative of delta function - chain rule for delta function containing a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, partial-derivative, dirac-delta, statistical-mechanics

I have a problem that relates to derivative of a delta function. The problem originates from a paper I was reading https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.2938860

In the paper, it is said that it is straightforward to see, as in equation (23), that:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{R}}\delta(\sum\limits_{i \in I} c_{I,i}\textbf{r}_i-\textbf{R}) = -\frac{1}{c_{I,k}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\textbf{r}_k} \delta(\sum\limits_{i \in I} c_{I,i}\textbf{r}_i-\textbf{R})$$

where $k$ can be any of $i \in I$, and I denotes a group of vectors $\textbf{r}_i$ for which $c_{I,i}\neq0$ for all $i$. $\textbf{R}$ is also a vector.

Is this correct? And how do you derive it in a simple way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same idea as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3172564/276986), be careful that the equality holds as distributions on the whole space. In general you need to make clear what is the distribution $\delta(\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n))$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$ for  $\phi : \Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ well behaved, to see the chain rule applies without problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Could you possibly expand your answer a bit more for this specific case? Also, I read your answer on the linked post, but I am not familiar with the notations and the meaning behind... Could you explain or provide some references so I can refer to?

Comment: Maybe this will help to clarify what kind of derivative is being taken: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Derivatives_of_distributions